# Lubuntu won't install using wubi (pastebin of log file included)

Tags: installation, wubi, lubuntu

So I tried to install lubuntu 2 times now, and it seems that it won't install because at the very last of the install progress I get the error: Could not retrieve the required installation files
for more ingormation, please see the log file (http://pastebin.com/kjJBfFe8)

I tried a live USB and it just doesn't boot up.

Anyone know what the problem could be?
I'm on a 64 bit i7 gtx560 system

Kind regards, Gilles

Comment: You need a working internet connection to install. What error message did you get when you booted the live usb?

Comment: Nothing, it just boots windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with Wubi 12.04 and Lubuntu. Ubuntu 12.04 is an LTS (long term support), but Lubuntu isn't LTS. So it hasn't been updated to 12.04.1 and 12.04.2.

Long story short, `wubi.exe` is looking for a Lubuntu 12.04.2 and not finding it so it fails. This is a [bug in Wubi](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1043607), but you can workaround it by using the original 12.04 `wubi.exe` from here: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/wubi-12.04.exe

It is better to install with the live USB, so you might want to look at this thread for help with this: [my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Why would that be better if i use live usb? And i dont get a black screen, windows kust starts without even noticing lubuntu.. But ill use the old wubi, ty fir that!

Comment: @user160045 oops, I meant it's better to install a normal dual boot. Wubi is better than running a live USB, a normal dual boot is better than Wubi.